# How I modify the following Python script to ignore tags and attributes within tags?

Tags: python, regex, xpath

How would I modify the following code to ignore tags (the < and > characters that represent start and end of tags) and attributes within tags while building up an XPath?

Below is a Python script which will read a formatted XML document and then determine the XPath from the current cursor position:

```
def buildPath(view, selection):
    path = ['']
    lines = []

    region = sublime.Region(0, selection.end())
    for line in view.lines(region):
        contents = view.substr(line)
        lines.append(contents)

    level = -1
    spaces = re.compile('^\s+')
    for line in lines:
        space = spaces.findall(line)
        current = len(space[0]) if len(space) else 0
        node = re.sub(r'\s*<\??([\w.]:)?([\w\-.]+)(\s.)?>.*', r'\2', line)
        if current == level:
            path.pop()
            path.append(node)
        elif current > level:
            path.append(node)
            level = current
        elif current < level:
            path.pop()
            level = current

    return path
```

Comment: Obligatory "why aren't you using a library"?

Comment: This is a python script which is from a plugin for SublimeText and the author didn't account for attributes and tag characters. I'm trying to modify it so that it does what I need it to do.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Is there a python library that gets xpath from XML?

Comment: @BrianTHannan `lxml` is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your copy of [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) (`pip install lxml`):

```
import lxml.etree
tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmlasstring)
tree.xpath('//node')
```